# Laravel: How to programmatically run job for 5 times if failed?

Tags: laravel, jobs

This is the code for job and I need to run the job after 5 seconds for only 5 times if it fails. Before diving into code, the `$this->attempts()` always return 1 so I didn't include it in code.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Order\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Modules\Order\Entities\Order;
use Modules\User\Entities\User;

class CreditPurchase implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private $order;
    private $user;
    private $paid_at;

    public function __construct(Order $order, User $user, $paid_at)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->paid_at = $paid_at;
    }


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $t = 4 / 0;

        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            $this->fail();
            $this->delete();
            $this->release(5);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> [2021-01-20 23:16:09] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '014c3080-3ee3-4198-946c-dfe1d8d858a7' for key 'failed_jobs_uuid_unique' (SQL: insert into `failed_jobs` (`uuid`, `connection`, `queue`, `payload`, `exception`, `failed_at`) values (014c3080-3ee3-4198-946c-dfe1d8d858a7, redis, default, {"uuid":"014c3080-3ee3-4198-946c-dfe1d8d858a7","timeout":null,"id":"HDww70Nm2TmRcmeO5cqXN8qrxbvzBfDq","backoff":null,"displayName":"Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"command":"O:33:"Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase":13:{s:40:"\u0000Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase\u0000order";O:45:"Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier":4:{s:5:"class";s:28:"Modules\Order\Entities\Order";s:2:"id";i:1;s:9:"relations";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"items";}s:10:"connection";s:5:"mysql";}s:39:"\u0000Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase\u0000user";O:45:"Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier":4:{s:5:"class";s:26:"Modules\User\Entities\User";s:2:"id";i:1;s:9:"relations";a:0:{}s:10:"connection";s:5:"mysql";}s:42:"\u0000Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase\u0000paid_at";O:13:"Carbon\Carbon":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2021-01-20 23:16:00.344324";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}s:3:"job";N;s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:15:"chainConnection";N;s:10:"chainQueue";N;s:19:"chainCatchCallbacks";N;s:5:"delay";i:2;s:11:"afterCommit";N;s:10:"middleware";a:0:{}s:7:"chained";a:0:{}}","commandName":"Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase"},"job":"Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call","attempts":1}, Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: Modules\Order\Jobs\CreditPurchase has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in C:\xampp\htdocs\avakala\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php:713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the `public $tries` property of the `Job` help you?

```
class CreditPurchase implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 5;

    //
}
```

We could also use a time-based attempt:

```
public function retryUntil()
{
    return now()->addSeconds(1);
}
```

Comment: It reports error `CreditPurchase has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.`

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to tell the queue worker to retry all of it's jobs 5 times

```php
php artisan queue:work --tries=5
```

> `public $tries = 5` and `public function retryUntil()` will take precedence over the --tries value provided on the command line and is a more granular approach